# HTML5 & JQueryMobile - Paging and Filtering a UL List

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, pagination, filtering

I am building a simple HTML5 app that has a Ul and filter as seen below:

```
<ul id="ItemsList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" >
```

This UL is populated dynamically from a Javascript method that executes on the pageshow of the div. Due to a large dataset i would like to be able to filter this list but at the same time keep the filtering option.

I cannot seem to find an example of such or any previous question. Does anyone know a good way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an Ajax solution or is the list items all loaded in the DOM? For the Ajax solution you can try http://listomatic.stakbit.com/ which makes an Ajax call with each tap/click for pagination and will work with the Search field enabled - making an Ajax call for the typed-in search string. I am the developer of this plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I just managed to write a write a jquery plugin for it as I did not find any good solution. I just completed it today and will take few days to upload it as free addin.
For now you can reach me at akhilesh.gandhi@gmail.com 
or here is solution

```
$.fn.scrollPagination.loadContent = function(obj, opts){
     var target = opts.scrollTarget;
     var mayLoadContent = $(target).scrollTop()+opts.heightOffset >= $(document).height() - $(target).height();
     if (mayLoadContent && (page <= noofpage)){
         if (opts.beforeLoad != null){
            opts.beforeLoad(); 
         }
         $(obj).children().attr('rel', 'loaded');
         var pageurl = opts.contentPage + "?q=" + opts.query + "&take=" + opts.take + "&skip=" + opts.skip + "&page=" + page + "&pagesize=" + opts.pagesize
         $.ajax({
              type: 'Get',
              url: pageurl,
              data: opts.contentData,
              success: function (data) {
                  noofpage = data[0].Count / opts.pagesize;
                  page = page + 1;
                $(obj).append(data); 
                var objectsRendered = $(obj).children('[rel!=loaded]');

                if (opts.afterLoad != null){
                    opts.afterLoad(data);
                }
              },
              dataType: 'json'
         });
     }

  };
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to apply to the OP's situation - can you clarify how this would help?